# Set tex box to accept only 1 letter

Tags: wpf, textbox

So I have `TextBox` and command:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLatter">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TextBoxKeyDownCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxLatter, Path=Text}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

**Command**

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{

}
```

And i want my `TextBox` accept only 1 `latter` to if the user type some `latter` it will delete the old one and show only the last one.

This is what i have try:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    TextBox textBox = parameter as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        string str = textBox.Text;
        textBox.Text = "";
        textBox.Text = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a reference to the `TextBox` control to the command in a view model breaks the MVVM pattern. You should bind `Text` to a source property:

```
private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
        {
            _text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            char last = value.Last();
            _text = last.ToString();
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLatter" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         MaxLength="1"/>
```

You shouldn't need an `EventTrigger` or a command.